# Teleporting back to the ship

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I don't understand why I can't get to do this, but how do I send my units back to my ship? I tried three times now and I can't seem to be able to get my units back (RIP 2 mantis on my last run).

Do I have to be in the same ship to be able to teleport them back? Should I only teleport to ships with teleporing systems?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**To teleport your crew members back:**

1. Make sure your teleporter is active (after using it to teleport crew members over, it will take a while for it to reset and be usable again).
2. Make sure the crew members you are trying to teleport are standing in a room, not entering or leaving it. (If they're busy fighting someone that's fine) .
3. Click on the bottom of the two teleportation icons.
4. Click on the room in the enemy ship which holds your crew members.

Comment: Two extra things to note: firstly, if you're out of danger (i.e., your boarders killed their entire crew and you're not in an asteroid field), your teleporter will charge instantaneously. Secondly, you can teleport waves of units in and out; if you for some reason only want to teleport one crew member out, you can still teleport the other crew member out later once your teleporter recharges again.

Comment: Note that there are *two* teleportation icons: the top one that points up and right, to send boarders to the other ship, and the bottom one that points down and left, to recall boarders.  It's not just one button.  If there's nobody in your teleporter room, the top one is grayed out; if there's nobody on the other ship, the bottom one is grayed out.

Comment: Also note that you can teleport 4 crew back, if you can get them all into the same room. Finally, if you do it while the game is paused (or the crew are on a cloaked ship) you'll have a little red teleport icon in their room until you unpause or the ship decloaks. Or they die.

Answer (score 4):

To teleport your crew back you must wait for the teleporter to recharge, then click the return button (there are 2 buttons for the teleporter, the return button is the one you didn't use to send them in), then click on a room on the enemy ship that has your guys. I believe they need to be in the same room to all be recalled, but I've never tried to test what would happen to the rest of the team if they weren't.

Keep in mind that if the enemy ship flees or blows up while your crew are on it, they will be lost forever.

Comment: they get lost when the enemy ftl's away or blows up...

Comment: @ewanm89 thanks, I should've mentioned that in the first place. Added.

Comment: FWIW, the return button is the bottom-most of the two teleport buttons.